# Change SQL Server date string ot other format

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Please forgive me for my dunglish, I am dutch.

I have a table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WSLogons]
(
    [Date] [nchar](15) NULL,
    [Time] [nchar](15) NULL,
    [Username] [nchar](15) NULL,
    [Domain] [nchar](15) NULL,
    [Computer] [nchar](15) NULL,
    [HostComputerName] [nchar](15) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

There is no primary key.

I fill this table with some user data and I made a big mistake well multiple but I am facing the fact that my date and time columns are filled wrong.

This is have solved but in my database I have different date and time formats.
and I am querying with a convert date and time function.

This is not working because in some rows, I have date and time values like this:

```
5/18/2018       9:00 AM         
5/18/2018       8:28 AM
```

and in some in the right way like this

```
18-05-2018      14:52
```

as I was saying, I query for information with a order by and a convert

```
order by CONVERT(date, Date, 105) desc
```

If in the results are date and time with the US notation, I get a format error.

Now I am as you can see not a SQL guru. I have corrected the script that is filling the table but now I want to convert the wrong dates into the right format so the data is saved.

I'd like to get a nice result in a query with this statement.

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(date, [Date] ,101) as datum
    ,[Time]
    ,[Username]
    ,[Domain]
    ,[Computer]
    ,[HostComputerName]
FROM 
    [AuditLogons].[dbo].[WSLogons] 
WHERE
    date LIKE '%/%/%' 
    AND Time LIKE '%:% AM%' OR Time LIKE '%:% PM%'
```

Now the `datum` column is presented as

```
2018-05-18  11:59 AM  
2018-05-18  1:25 PM
```

How do I get from here to update those rows in formatting the date like `18-5-2018`?

If I try to convert to do

```
CONVERT(date, [Date], 105)
```

I get an error, too.

Hope you can understand my problem and I hope for some help

Many thanks.
Roger

Comment: `[Date] [nchar](15)` <=== that's the fundamental problem; the database has the `datetime` type and the `date` type and the `time` type; dates/times *stored as dates/times* don't *have* a concept of "format". Is refactoring the database a viable option?

Comment: Any hopes to make the date column actually a DATE datatype? And the Time column a TIME datatype?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, but the underlying issue is that rule number one of database design is to use the appropriate data types. If you can change those columns, do it; if you can't, make sure you are validating your input.

```
DECLARE @WSLogons TABLE(
    [Date] [nchar](15) NULL,
    [Time] [nchar](15) NULL
)

INSERT INTO @WSLogons ([Date],[Time]) SELECT '5/18/2018','9:00 AM'
INSERT INTO @WSLogons ([Date],[Time]) SELECT '5/18/2018','09:00'

SELECT *
    ,CONVERT(datetime2, [Date] + ' ' + [Time]) as datum
FROM @WSLogons
```

Answer (score 0):

first add real date column to your table:

```
alter table dbo.WSLogons add realDate datetime;
```

then update it with proper data ie:

```
update dbo.WSLogons
set realDate = CONVERT(datetime, Date, 101)
where Date like '[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

for date format in **dd/mm/yyyy** style
for other formats see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)